# how to check if one header include another header in c++?

Tags: c++, include

how to check if one header include another header in c++?

for example, When I want to know if the  include , but the  include two many headers and header include other headers.So I have to check the source code one by one, So is there any quick method to find if one include another?

Comment: Check the header guard macro?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an include guard. This will ensure the compiler does not include the header contents more than once.

An example header file, `MyClass.h`, using a standard include guard:

```
// MyClass.h

#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

// Your header contents goes here

#endif
```

This will ensure that the compiler only includes the header contents once.

Alternatively, you can use `#pragma once`.

An example header file, `MyClass.h`, using non-standard `#pragma once`:

```
// MyClass.h

#pragma once

// Your header contents goes here
```

Note that `#pragma once` is not standard, so it will make your code less portable. However, it does use less code, and can avoid name clashes.

Comment: `_MYCLASS_H` is a reserved identifier in C (which C++ inherits): https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL37-C.+Do+not+declare+or+define+a+reserved+identifier. one should not use this form to declare a header include guard.

Comment: Ah, good point! Edited my original post to correct the example.
Fortunately, it turned out to be a good demonstration of the value of `#pragma once`.

Comment: Does `#pragma once` also avoid the need of redundant include guards?

Answer (score 0):

If `myheader.h` has what we call an *include guard*, then it will usually `#define` a macro with a name like `MYHEADER_H`. So first check whether your header file has this kind of thing.

If it does, you can check at any point whether it has been included (up to that point), using the `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` directives.

Answer (score 0):

in some cases, the header guard mentioned in other answers will not suffice (e.g. your file is used on multiple systems or is built against separate versions or libraries and the hguard is inconsistent). In those cases, you can:

- look for another identifier which is `#define`d in that header
- or simply replace your inclusion of that header with your own little wrapper header which has a `#define` which does not vary by platform/architecture, then replace your `#include`s with the wrapper header. To illustrate:

  ```
  #ifndef MON_HGUARD_CXX_CSTDIO
  #define MON_HGUARD_CXX_CSTDIO

  // now replace the following #include with inclusion of this header
  #include <cstdio>

  #endif // MON_HGUARD_CXX_CSTDIO
  ```